# How do I convert milliseconds to dd:hh:mm using moment.js?

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to get the days, hours and minutes of 9000000 milliseconds, but moment.js is returning 0 days. I'm using Format plugin for the Moment Duration object. https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

```
moment.duration(9000000, "milliseconds").format("dd:hh:mm");
```

returns "02:30"

How did I get 9000000?

```
var ms = moment.duration({
    days: 1,
    hours: 2,
    minutes: 30,
})

console.log(ms._milliseconds);

// 9000000
```

Comment: Could you share your code? So we see what you have done wrong?!

Comment: calculate what actually is 9000000 millis, accept my answer and move on! there is no mistake, error or bug in the code. there is one in your calculations.

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks 9000000 ms is actually 1 day 2 hours and 30 mins. that's why I'm asking the right way to convert it or to get the days, hours and minutes of it.

Comment: No, it is not [what google says](https://www.google.lv/search?q=milliseconds+in+a+day&oq=millise&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0l2j69i60j69i61.3037j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: 9000000 millis = 9000000 / 1000 = 9000 seconds = 9000 / 60 = 150 mins = 150 / 60 = 2.5 hours. Write your manual calculations of how you got 1 day of 9 million milliseconds!

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks thanks for your time. I've edited my post for reference.

Comment: have you tried `ms.milliseconds();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like humanizeduration is what you are looking for:
humanizeDuration(97320000)  // '1 day, 3 hours, 2 minutes'

Here is the github link:
https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js

Answer (score -1):

1000 x 60 x 60 x 24 = 86'400'000 milliseconds.
Of course 9 mil is 0 days. 
9'000'000 / (1000 x 60 x 60) = 2.5h = 2 hours 30 min 
I hope I know how to use calculator 
[Check this place](http://convert-units.info/time/millisecond/9000000)